# Django Multi Tenant Admin Page Users

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi tenant app.  Tenants are seperated by the domains.
Each tenant have Members and Member class has a onetoone realtion to User model. See code below. For each Tenant at least a few Members has users with admin privilages. I can filter all models (created by me) to show in admin page which belong to that tenant.
But whatever I do users and groups are shown for all tenants.

I want to show the Users ( from django.contrib.auth.models)  which belong to that tenant.

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subdomain=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class TenantAwareModel(models.Model):
    tenant=models.ForeignKey(Tenant,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Member(TenantAwareModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_ROLES,default=USER_NOTSET)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
```

First issue is that I need to able to change what shows in the admin page for Users but since user is already added to the admin by `auth.UserAdmin` I can not call`@admin.register(User)`

1. Can I unregister and register User again.
2. If the answer to 1 question if NO do I have to have a customuser model so I can overwrite the Usermodel in the admin(I do not know creating a custom user also adds another model to admin page or removes the Users and instead show CustomUser under Groups.

Basically I want to do something like this.

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ["name"]
    def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request, *args, **kwargs)
        tenant = get_tenant(request) //returns tenant from url 
        query all members from this tenant and list the users of these members. Here each member has a onetoone relation to a User 
        return queryset
```

Or is there a better way to only show the users which belong to a certain tenant?

Do people create custom admin pages for this sort of thing from scratch?

Thanks